# Binding a nested List in XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

My ViewModel looks like this:

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public List<Paragraph> Paragraphs { get; set; }
    . . .
}

public class Paragraph
{
    public List<ParagraphElement> Elements; 
    . . .
}
```

And my XAML looks like this:

```
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Paragraphs}">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ParagraphElements}" />
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
```

I get the following error: 
    "**XamlParseException**"

and the Additional information: 
    '**Add value to collection of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection' 
     threw an exception.**'

How can I bind this nestes structure in XAML ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to set ItemTemplate for outer ItemsControl. Exception is thrown because you set ItemsSource for outer ItemsControl and added an inner ItemsControl  to Items collection at the same time

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Paragraphs}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate> 
          <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Green">
             <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}" 
                           ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ParagraphElements}" />
          </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Now i dont get error. But i see nothing except n rectangles with green borders, where n = number of parapgrahs.

Comment: @moller1111, in your sample `public List<ParagraphElement> Elements;` is a field. `Binding` needs a property, there should be a message in Output window about binding error. change your code like this: `public List<ParagraphElement> Elements {get;set;}` (similar to `Paragraphs`). Didn't notice that first time